# How to assign TextField value to Data Class

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to assign the TextField values to a data model class in jetpackCompose way . For ex

In viewModel if i have a function like this

```
 fun addProducts(product: Product) = viewModelScope.launch {
    addProductResponse = Response.Loading
    addProductResponse = useCases.product(product)
}
```

In my compose having two or more TextFields how to assign the values to data class and pass it on the button click unit

```
@Composable
fun ProductUploadSection(viewModel: UploadViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {

Column(Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
    val productName = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
    val productAbout = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
    val productPrice = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
    TextField(value = productName.value,
        onValueChange = { productName.value = it },
        maxLines = 1,
        placeholder = { Text(text = "Product Title") })
    
    TextField(value = productAbout.value,
        onValueChange = { productAbout.value = it },
        maxLines = 1,
        placeholder = { Text(text = "Product About") })
    
    Button(onClick = {viewModel.addProducts(//How to assign model class) }) {
```

Model Class of Product

```
data class Product(
var product_name:String,
var product_id:String,
var product_about:String,
var product_price:Int? = null
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In viewmodel create

```
val productState = mutableState<Product>(Product())
```

, where Product() has default values.
Then add data to your productState in onValueChange:

```
onValueChange = { 
viewModel.productState.value = viewModel.productState.value.copy(product_name = "Milk")
```

}

And when new value added to productState it will be refreshed in button:

```
 Button {Text(text = viewModel.productState.value.product_name)}
```